How to work with Flutter for web that is already in github?
I have a Flutter project for my friend's website, in github repository.
I want to use IDX, to allow my friend to easily make simple changes.
Questions:

How to clone existing project to IDX workspace?  If i run git clone in terminal, it will create subdirectory, so my .vscode will lose power.
How to share the workspace with friend?
How to run project for web/chrome from idx console/workspace?

Copy in idx: https://community.idx.dev/t/how-to-work-with-flutter-for-web-that-is-already-in-github/795?u=polina-c

Seems idx team added, Import a repo button in their home page today or recently. For the devices to show in the window, one can update the .idx/dev.nix file like this

IDX now has the option to directly Import a repo link on their home page or click here . For the devices to show in the window in the right pane, one can update the .idx/dev.nix file like here .
Answer before 23 July 2024
I had a similar situation and here is what I did.

In IDX, create an app ( say flutter app ).
Once the VSCode window opens, navigate to Menu --> Terminal --> New Terminal.
In the terminal cd .. out of that directory and do git clone --filter=blob:none https://github.com/flutter/samples.git. Unfortunately I could not copy paste here. ( Needs browser permissions I assume ). Remaining steps are similar to running VSCode locally.
Once cloned, navigate to the app directory Menu --> File --> Open Folder. Open the sample folder say /home/user/samples/material_3_demo/.
Click the play icon on sidebar or Run and debug, select Flutter and Dart and click on the play button there.
The app should run on the Android or Web on the right window.
Opening the same created app in IDX again should now open from the new folder.

If you see a rebuild pop up window, say cancel as this can open a new browser tab.
For the devices to show in the window, one can update the .idx/dev.nix file like this. More info here
PS - Try to create a flutter app, as it has the Android or the Web output on the right otherwise it will run but one may not be able to see the output.
